# opencart: how to add a exclude_categories filter to product/category

Tags: mysql, opencart

I am working with an opencart system and i would like to add an exclude_categories filter. I have done the PHP side of things and need help fixing the SQL.

```
    if (!empty($data['filter_sub_category']) && !empty($data['filter_exclude_categories'])) {

        $implode = array();

        $exclude_categories = explode(',', $data['filter_exclude_categories']);

        foreach ($exclude_categories as $cat_id) {
            $implode[] = (int)$cat_id;
        }
        $sql .= " AND cp.path_id NOT IN (" . implode(',', $implode) . ")";  
    }
```

For people not familiar with oc the `category_path` table looks like this.

<kbd>category_id</kbd>
    <kbd>path_id</kbd>
    <kbd>level</kbd> 

             <kbd>1</kbd>        
         <kbd>1</kbd>     
       <kbd>0</kbd>   

             <kbd>2</kbd>        
         <kbd>1</kbd>     
       <kbd>0</kbd>   

             <kbd>2</kbd>        
         <kbd>2</kbd>     
       <kbd>1</kbd>   

             <kbd>3</kbd>        
         <kbd>1</kbd>     
       <kbd>0</kbd>   

             <kbd>3</kbd>        
         <kbd>2</kbd>     
       <kbd>1</kbd>   

             <kbd>3</kbd>        
         <kbd>3</kbd>     
       <kbd>2</kbd>

Lets give these categories a name.

`category_id 1 == 'products'`

`category_id 2 == 'products->mens'`

`category_id 3 == 'products->mens->footwear'`

When given a category_id all products are returned for this category and its sub categories.

This works by using path_id rather than the category_id.

```
$sql .= " AND cp.path_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_category_id'] . "'";
```

If `$data['filter_category_id'] == 1` then the category_id's used to fetch products are `(1,2,3)`

Now if I wanted to exclude all products from the `mens(2)` category the only category id which should be used to fetch products is `(1)` but the same results are showing whether I exclude a category or not.

I think its because the category_id's are still returned under a different path_id.

<kbd>category_id</kbd>
    <kbd>path_id</kbd>
    <kbd>level</kbd> 

             <kbd>1</kbd>        
         <kbd>1</kbd>     
       <kbd>0</kbd>   

             <kbd>2</kbd>        
         <kbd>1</kbd>     
       <kbd>0</kbd>   

             <kbd>2</kbd>        
         <kbd>2</kbd>     
       <kbd>1</kbd>   //<-- row removed

             <kbd>3</kbd>        
         <kbd>1</kbd>     
       <kbd>0</kbd>   

             <kbd>3</kbd>        
         <kbd>2</kbd>     
       <kbd>1</kbd>   //<-- row removed

             <kbd>3</kbd>        
         <kbd>3</kbd>     
       <kbd>2</kbd>

Adding

```
$sql .= " AND cp.category_id NOT IN (" . implode(',', $implode) . ")";
```

would result in

<kbd>category_id</kbd>
    <kbd>path_id</kbd>
    <kbd>level</kbd> 

             <kbd>1</kbd>        
         <kbd>1</kbd>     
       <kbd>0</kbd>   

             <kbd>2</kbd>        
         <kbd>1</kbd>     
       <kbd>0</kbd>   //<-- row removed

             <kbd>2</kbd>        
         <kbd>2</kbd>     
       <kbd>1</kbd>   //<-- row removed

             <kbd>3</kbd>        
         <kbd>1</kbd>     
       <kbd>0</kbd>   

             <kbd>3</kbd>        
         <kbd>2</kbd>     
       <kbd>1</kbd>   //<-- row removed

             <kbd>3</kbd>        
         <kbd>3</kbd>     
       <kbd>2</kbd>

but this would leave footwear(category_id=3)

any ideas ?

Here is the source of what i'm working with  [catalog/model/catalog/product.php#L99](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/model/catalog/product.php#L99), i have bookmarked where i would insert the code (line 99)